# How do I upload a file from the command line to satisfy a Dropbox file request?

Tags: unix, dropbox

Context: I have a problem with some software that I am using. I contacted the software's tech support and they said they could run their pipeline themselves to see if they can see something differen. They supplied me with a Dropbox file request. It is just a link for a website with a button to upload files from local.

However, these files are reaching terabytes. I can't transfer them locally. And especially not twice--my VPN/internet will likely cut at some point either downloading it locally or uploading it from local.

I've tried a few different methods to move my files from our Ubuntu server to their Dropbox:

The first is [dbxcli](https://github.com/dropbox/dbxcli). However, I don't see how I can upload files to someone else's account--this only allows me to upload to my own dropbox account. Since I'm on the FREE dropbox account tier, I get 2GB of storage, NOT 2TB. I can't exactly upload and share that way.

Next was using a stackoverflow user's tool call [Dropbox-Uploader](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader). Unfortunately, that's the same issue...

What about just using `curl`? Surely, anywhere with an address can just be sent data, right? Well, if we go to the documentation for the [dropbox API for uploading](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload), we can see that the 'path' argument for the API call is a RELATIVE path for your OWN Dropbox account. And while you can manage the file requests that YOU send out, I can't see a way to manage other user's file requests that you want to fulfill.

I was inspired to try the above for maybe a little too long after coming across [this hopeful response](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Using-Curl-amp-Dropbox-API-to-upload-files-to-a-DB-request-link/m-p/518878/highlight/true#M25353) to someone 2 years ago with my question.

So, has anyone attempted this before? If not, any pointers of where to look next? I'm pretty sure the Python SDK will be similar to the other applications I've installed...

Comment: It doesn't look like the Dropbox public API allows satisfying a file request; it can only create/modify/delete FRs that you own (not ones that are requested of you): https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_requests-count - so your best bet is probably to reverse-engineer the web request and hack a curl command for it, which probably shoudn't be too bad.